# Multiples rutas estáticas (Linux)

Tags: linux

**Hola!** Necesito ayuda con un tema de rutas.
Les comento mi situación: Tengo dos edificios conectados por un "punto a punto", funciona sin inconvenientes, peeeero de vez en cuando se cae.
Cuando se cae, tenemos configurada una VPN, configuramos la ruta y todo funciona sin problemas.
Tengo un servidor en cada extremo.

Me gustaría que el failOver sea automático.

Para ser mas especifico:

**Edificio 1:**
***· Server CENTOS***

```
·· eth0: 192.168.12.11
·· tun0 10.8.0.1
·· GATEWAY: 192.168.12.254
```

Tabla de Ruteo:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.8.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.12.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.10.0    192.168.12.254  255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.12.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

Actualmente está saliendo por el Punto a Punto:

```
192.168.10.0/24 via 192.168.12.254 dev eth0
```

**Edificio 2:**
***· Server CENTOS***

```
·· em1: 192.168.10.4
·· tun0: 10.8.0.6
·· GATEWAY: 192.168.10.254
```

Tabla de Ruteo:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.8.0.5        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.8.0.0        10.8.0.5        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.12.0    192.168.10.254  255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 em1
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 em1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 em1
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 em1
```

Actualmente está saliendo por el Punto a Punto:

```
192.168.12.0/24 via 192.168.10.254 dev em1
```

--
Cada vez que quiero que salga por la VPN, cambio la ruta y funciona sin problemas.
Pero no encuentro la forma de que el cambio de rutas sea automático (failover).
¿Me darian una mano?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creo que este [gist](https://gist.github.com/Apsu/5021255) te podría funcionar, solo necesitas adaptarlo a tus necesidades. Básicamente lo que necesitas es detectar cuando ya no alcances el gateway del enlace para hacer el cambio a la conexión vpn.

En el script solo necesitas cambiar las interfaces y los gateways.